# Struggling with pointers to functions and references

Tags: c++

I am working through this problem I found on Git to brush up on some skills. Using `friend` is prohibited. C++ styling should be used compared to C.

Essentially, I cannot call the `identify()` function that belongs to the `Brain` member variable in my `Human` class. It just will not let me access it. If you can code this up, and explain where I am going wrong, that would be great.

> Create a Brain class, with whatever you think befits a brain. It will have an Identify() function that returns a string containing the brain's address in memory, in hex format, prefixed by 0x.
>
> Then, make a Human class, that has a constant Brain attribute with the same lifetime. It has an identify() function, that just calls the identity() function of its Brain and returns its result.
>
> Now, make it so this code compiles and displays two identical addresses:
>
> ```cpp
> int main(){
>     Human bob;
>     std::cout << bob.identify() << "\n";
>     std::cout << bob.getBrain().identify() << "\n";
> }
> ```

Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Brain.h"

class Human
{
    const Brain humanBrain;

public:
    Human();
    std::string identify();
};
```

```cpp
#include "Human.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

Human::Human()
{
    this->humanBrain = new Brain;
}

std::string Human::identify()
{
    Brain b = this->humanBrain.identify(); // This is essentially what I am trying to call--and I can't access it.
    const Brain * ptr = humanBrain;
    std::ostringstream test;
    test << ptr;
    return test.str();
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Brain
{
    int age;
    std::string gender;
    void* ptr;
public:
    Brain();
    //std::string getBrain();
    const std::string identify();
    void setPtr(void* p);
};
```

```cpp
#include "Brain.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

Brain::Brain()
{
    age = 10;
    gender = "male";
}

const std::string Brain::identify()
{
    //const Brain* bPtr = &this;
    const Brain* bPtr = this;
    ptr = this;
    std::ostringstream test;
    test << &bPtr;
    std::string output = "Brain Identify: 0x" + test.str();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: "Picture not uploading" -- hooray! Finally, no more utterly worthless, and useless pictures on Stackoverflow, they finally banned them!! You can always upload your pictures to Facebook or Twitter, where they belong, while Stackoverflow contains only questions that get asked in plain text, so they can be easily copy-pasted for further research. P.S.: it sounds like your C++ textbook is horrible. It doesn't even use the correct C++ terminology. It's "class member" instead of "attribute". What C++ textbook did you read this terminology from?

Comment: Why are you using pointers for this assignment?  Nothing suggests usage of pointers, and especially `void` pointers.  Then `this->humanBrain = new Brain;` -- this couldn't have compiled, since `humanBrain` is not a pointer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik • did they really **ban** them?  I thought the poster just needed sufficient rep.  Enough rep to know better than to post one.

Comment: `Brain b = this->humanBrain.identify();`: (1) Why are you trying to initialize an instance of `Brain` with a `std::string` argument? This makes no sense. Fix that before moving any further. (2) Drop `this->`; it’s redundant in that context.

Comment: I can only hope, @Eljay... Besides, there's plenty of misdirected Facebook cat pictures uploads here, from 1 rep users...

Comment: A hint: `std::string Human::identify() const { return humanBrain.identify(); }` How hard can it be?

Comment: Another hint: [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek no need for `std::hex` since `operator<<` prints pointers in hex. `std::hex` only applies to integers

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Ok, so can you explain to me why moving "const" to AFTER the function declaration (at the end) allowed me to access the Identify on the member humanBrain? And when I create getBrain here, it returns a different address than the bob.identify. Why? Brain(Human::getBrain() const) { return this->humanBrain; } –

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it didn't compile-- I had humanBrain as a pointer initially, and it did at the time. But in the process of figuring this problem out, I changed it. And while yes the problem doesn't explicitly mention pointers, the problem set is titled "Memory allocation, References, Pointers to members, File streams".

And one of the earlier problems was using pointers.

Comment: @agile_flow I address the `const` issue in my answer. You should have lead with that in your question, ie by providing the actual error you were getting. As for the `getBrain()` issue, you are returning the `Brain` object *by value*, thus you are returning a *copy* of the `humanBrain` member. You need to return it *by reference* instead, as I also showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Human::humanBrain` member is declared as type `const Brain`, which is correct per the instructions, however your `Brain::identify()` method is not qualified as `const`, so you can't call it on any `const Brain` object.  This is the root of the problem that you are having trouble with.

In addition, there are many other problems with your code, as well:

- `Human::humanBrain` is not a pointer, so using `new` to construct it is wrong.  And, you don't need a pointer to get the address of a variable anyway.  Nor do you actually need a pointer to the member at all in this project.
- `Human` lacks a `getBrain()` method, so `bob.getBrain()` in `main()` will not compile, per the instructions.
- `Human::identify()` is calling `humanBrain.identify()`, which returns a `std::string` as it should, but is then assigning that string to a local `Brain` variable, which is wrong (not to mention, you are not even using that variable for anything afterwards).  The instructions clearly state that `Human::identity()` should simply call `Brain::identify()` and return its result, but you are not doing that.
- `Brain::identify()` is printing the address of its local variable `bPtr` rather than printing the address of the `Brain` object that `identify()` is begin called on, per the instructions.

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

Human.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Brain.h"
#include <string>

class Human
{
    const Brain humanBrain;

public:
    Human() = default;
    std::string identify() const;
    const Brain& getBrain() const;
};
```

Human.cpp

```
#include "Human.h"

std::string Human::identify() const
{
    return humanBrain.identity();
}

const Brain& Human::getBrain() const
{
    return humanBrain;
}
```

Brain.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Brain
{
    int age;
    std::string gender;
public:
    Brain();
    std::string identify() const;
};
```

Brain.cpp

```
#include "Brain.h"
#include <sstream>

Brain::Brain()
{
    age = 10;
    gender = "male";
}

std::string Brain::identify() const
{
    std::ostringstream test;
    test << "Brain Identify: 0x" << this;
    return test.str();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so can you explain to me why moving "const" to AFTER the function declaration (at the end) allowed me to access the Identify on the member humanBrain?

And when I create getBrain here, it returns a different address than the bob.identify. Why?

Brain(Human::getBrain() const)  {
 return this->humanBrain;
}

Comment: @agile_flow I updated my answer to address the `const` issue. You should have lead with that in your question, ie by providing the actual error you were getting. As for the `getBrain()` issue, you are returning the `Brain` object *by value*, thus you are returning a *copy* of the `humanBrain` member. You need to return it *by reference* instead, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: thank you. I was getting confused to where the const actually binded to.
Good catch on the 

"Brain::identify() is printing the address of its local variable bPtr rather than printing the address of the Brain object that identify() is begin called on, per the instructions."

I didn't understand that but I do now.

Going forward, what would you say would be my best learning resource in this area? I understand passing by value and reference, but being wrapped up in a bigger example here confuses me sometimes.

Comment: @agile_flow "*Going forward, what would you say would be my best learning resource in this area?*" - to stop learning from random online examples, and instead to get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).